# touchstart event Chrome Android issue

Tags: android, addeventlistener, touchstart

I have a `touchstart` eventlistener attached to a button and when I touch it on Android Firefox, it fires normally. On Chrome (Android) though, it won't fire at all. Any reasons why? Changing to event to `click` obviously works, but I need touch.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5hg8847k/) (works with mobile)

Answer (score 1):

I may have found the answer..
I don't know why, but it seems to work if I add `e.preventDefault()` to touchstart event.

I'm just adding a double click functionality for mouse and single click functionality for touch on my element, that is why I need to register both click and touch events.

By preventing default behaviour I seem to be able to simulate the 300ms click delay that mobile browsers used to have (as far as I know).